# How to change the background color of each field based on field value like excel

Tags: custom-list

Does anyone know how you can change the background color of list fields same as it excel based on field value. value may be change by the time . I know several ways to do it by row or item record (by using conditionally formatting ) but this is specifically to be able to change value and  applied conditional formatting based on the value of the field I have this sharepoint list that has around 200 rows and 40 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could suggest two approaches here:

1.) Create a Data View Webpart in Sharepoint Designer.

2.) Create a Calculated column of type number and you can add html there.

I would suggest first one, because there are 40 columns and for the second approach you will have to create an extra column for each column.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, HTML/JavaScript in a Calculated Column which colors the row, or cells might be an option for you.

This colors the row based on the Priority field (detailed explanation [here](http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How))

```
=[Priority]
&IF([Task Status]="Not Started" , "" ,
  &"<img src=""/_layouts/images/blank.gif"" onload=""{"
  &"this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='#"
  &CHOOSE( RIGHT( LEFT( [Priority] , 2) , 1) , "fab" , "fda" , "9fa" )
  &"';"
  &"}"">" 
)
```

If you want to access individual cells in a row you have to walk the Row with NextSibling JavaScript calls.
Best approach is to write the JavaScript first in JSFiddle or Plunkr, once it works wrap the lines in **&""** to stuff it in a Calculated Column